# How to remove unnecessary elements from an array B so that only duplicate digits are left following each other

Tags: c++, arrays, function

Task: Array B should consist of numbers from array A, in which there are 2 identical consecutive numbers. Make the search itself for 2 consecutive numbers as a function. Faced the problem that I cannot indicate the correct value of the values ​​after finding 2 consecutive characters.It turns out that cells that have no value are initialized.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;



int* read_array(int N)  // Dynamic A
{
int* read_array = new int[N];

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    read_array[i] = rand() % 3;
}

return read_array;

}



int* check_read_array(int arr[],int N)  // Dynamic B from A with following digits
 {
int* check_read_array = new int[N];

int Count = 0;

for (int j = 1; j < N; j++)
{
    if (arr[j] == arr[j - 1])
    {
        check_read_array[Count++] = arr[j];
    }
}

return check_read_array;

 }




void print_array(int arr[], int N) // Array A
{
cout << "\nArray A" << endl;

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    cout << arr[i] << endl;
}

}

 void print_array_checked(int checked_array[], int N) // Array B
{
cout << "\nArray B" << endl;

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    cout << checked_array[i] << endl;
}

}


int main()
{
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

//bool asc = true; 

int N = 0; 

cout << "Введите размерность и количество элементов массива" << endl;

cin >> N;

cout << "Введенное число = " << N << endl;

int* arr = read_array(N); //Array A

int* checked_array = check_read_array(arr, N); //Array B






print_array(arr, N); //Print Array A

print_array_checked(checked_array, N); //Print Array B


//Clear dynamic memory

delete[] arr;
delete[] checked_array;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated, just for the sanity of all that is still right in the world (which ain't much), don't name local variables the same as the function they reside in.

Comment: Unrelated: Why are you using raw pointers for this? Use `std::vector<int>` and then you don't have to delete the memory afterwards - or send the size as a separate argument to functions.